# JS not in the same script balise

Tags: javascript, function

Hi everyone!

```
   <script>
     error();
   </script>


<script>
function error(){
alert('erreur');
}
</script>
```

The function "error" isn't called. I know this is useless but I want to know why it's doesn't work.

Comment: At a guess it's because `error();` is executed before the function is defined. Your browser's error console probably shows that. In Javascript, functions are defined as part of normal execution flow, not in a separate compilation step.

Answer (score 1):

When the first `<script>` is executed, the `error` function is not yet defined. You should get an exception stating that in your error console.

While usually in JavaScript [hoisting applies for function declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14299659/questions-on-javascript-hoisting), this does not work across scripts (in syntax terms: across *Program* texts). Changing your script to the following would make it work:

```
<script>
   error();

   function error() {
       alert('erreur');
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Across _inline_ `<scrip>` tags.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp: It's the same for external scripts.

Comment: Correct. Works within one external script or inline `<script>` tag but not across any of those.