# Javascript Global Scope Assignment

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I understand the issues with global scope and javascript variables and their general undesirability; and that you find them everywhere. The following (in a browser) is equivalent:

```
var foo = 3; // foo === 3, window.foo === 3
bazz = 10; // bazz === 10, window.bazz === 10
```

Declaring a variable with the var keyword in the global scope is the same as declaring it without a var anywhere in the code: your variable is assigned to the root (window) object.

One technique I see a lot (e.g. setting up google analytics) is this:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
```

... and I follow the reasoning that if _gaq has been declared use that, if not create it as an array. It allows careless coding not to overwrite any values already assigned to the global variable _gaq.

What I don't understand is why this throws an error:

```
_gaq = _gaq || [];
```

They look equivalent to me: _gaq should take the value of _gaq or be initialised as an array. But it throws a reference error - my question is: why are they different?

Comment: They're not exactly equivalent, they differ in behavior when you try to [`delete`](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/) them.

Comment: The best explanation of 'undeclared assignments' and why they're different to global assignments (`foo=0`!=`var foo=0` in the global scope) I can find is **[on this blog](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/)** which has helped me understand the intrinsic difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can never **read** variables which have not been declared, and that's what you are trying with the expression `_gaq || []` in the last case.

In this case

```
 _gaq = _gaq || [];
```

`_qaq` has not been declared before and when the right hand side (`_gaq || []`) is evaluated, it throws the error.

Here is step by step explanation of what is going on in this case:

The assignment operator is described in [section 11.13.1](http://es5.github.com/#x11.13.1) of the specification:

> The production `AssignmentExpression : LeftHandSideExpression = AssignmentExpression` is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let `lref` be the result of evaluating `LeftHandSideExpression`.
> 2. Let `rref` be the result of evaluating `AssignmentExpression`.
> ...

`LeftHandSideExpression` is `_gaq`, the `AssignmentExpression` is `_gqa || []`.

So first `_qaq` is evaluated, which results in an [***unresolvable reference***](http://es5.github.com/#x8.7), since the variable `_gaq` is not declared. This evaluation **does not** throw an error.

Then `_gqa || []` is evaluated. This is a `LogicalORExpression` and is described in [section 11.11](http://es5.github.com/#x11.11) as `LogicalORExpression || LogicalANDExpression`. In this case, `LogicalORExpression`, the left hand side, is `_gaq` and `LogicalANDExpression`, the right hand side, is `[]`.
The expression is evaluated as follows:

> 1. Let `lref` be the result of evaluating `LogicalORExpression`.
> 2. Let `lval` be `GetValue(lref)`.
> ...

We already know that `lref` will be an unsolvable reference because `_gaq` was not declared. So lets have a look what `GetValue` is doing (defined in [section 8.7.1](http://es5.github.com/#x8.7.1), `V` is the value passed to `GetValue`):

> 1. If `Type(V)` is not `Reference`, return `V`.
> 2. Let `base` be the result of calling `GetBase(V)`.
> 3. If `IsUnresolvableReference(V)`, throw a `ReferenceError` exception.
> ...

As you can see, a `ReferenceError` error is thrown in the third step of this procedure, which in turn gets executed by evaluating the right hand side of the assignment, and this is where the error is thrown.

**So, why does this not happen with `var _gaq = _gaq || [];` ?**

This line:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
```

is actually

```
var _gaq;
_gaq = _gaq || [];
```

because of something called [hoisting *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Scope_Cheatsheet#Hoisting). That means when `_gaq` is evaluated, it will **not** result in an *unresolvable reference*, but a reference with value `undefined`.

(If the variable `_gaq` is already declared (and potentially has a value), then `var _gaq` won't have any effect.)

---

If you want to create `_gaq` globally from inside a function, do it *explicitly* by referring to `window`:

```
window._gaq = window._gaq || [];
```

Comment: That looks right! "You can never read variables which have not been declared" , I'm not I agree with this statement. `window.x` for example reads fine and returns the primitive value type `undefined` if the variable `x` has not been declared in `window` (assuming we did not define `window.x` )

Comment: @Benjamin: But in this case, `window.x` is a property of the `window` object, not a variable. And although global variables are properties of the global object, it's not that you access the `window` object, when you reference a global variable "implicitly", the properties of `window` are just put into the functions scope chain.

Comment: Thank you that makes it much clearer. However, it suggests the question: what 'magic' is occurring when one simply writes 'foo = 10'? If the javascript engine infers or creates an implicit 'var foo;' statement, then why doesn't it do so for my example?

Comment: That's interesting, I'm not sure I understand the distinction. Would you mind explaining why `x` throws a `ReferenceError` while this.x throws `undefined` while they usually mean the same thing?

Comment: @PartyArk: `foo = 10;` does not create an implicit `var foo`, it will create a property `foo` on the `window` element. As bfavaretto already mentioned, the problem is not on the left hand side of `=` but on the right hand side.

Comment: Now I'm more confused! Are var foo = 10 and foo = 10 _not_ equivalent (in the global scope)? Obviously both result in window.foo = 10.

Comment: @Benjamin: Just because `window.x` (or `this.x`) is a property access and `x` is a variable access. They can refer to the same value but it is accessed via different paths.

Comment: That's interesting, thanks. Can you refer me to some reading material about the differences? (The reference error obviously being one)

Comment: @PartyArk: Not completely, as Bergi mentioned in his comment. But again, the problem is not `x = ....` it is `... = x || y;` where `x` is not declared.

Comment: @Benjamin: I don't have any reference that explains this well, I can only refer you to the specification: http://es5.github.com/#x8.7.1.

Comment: I read the spec :) To be honest I just wanted to see if you could provide a more intuitive explanation then the formal definition there. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 4):

If the `_gaq` to the right of `=` was not previous declared with `var`, it will throw a reference error. You're trying to reference a variable that does not exist. The "magic" just works for *assigning* to non-existing variables.

It's just like saying `x = y + 1`; the problem is not the non-existing `x`, but the non-existing `y`.

Comment: Thanks. So I understand that the engine tries to work out the value of the variable and errors because it's not been declared. That makes sense. Where I had it wrong is that just leaving off the 'var' for globals is not a shorthand/optional way of declaring them, even though that's the way it mostly looks.

Comment: @Part: No, omitting the `var` is ok as shorthand. The problem is not writing to an undeclared variable, it's reading one. Just as in the example in this answer `x = y + 1`. `x` would become global if `y` was declared but since it isn't it will throw an error that `y` is not declared. The right hand side is evaluate first, so in the case of `x = x || 42;` you are trying to read `x` before it is created.

Comment: See above, but I think it's really important to understand that the hoisting only occurs when you write var _even in the global scope_, and hence `var x=x||0` works but  `x=x||0` doesn't. You might say 'well obviously' but unless you're 'short circuiting' in this fashion it _does_ appear that a global var is just cruft. Hence my initial confusion. Thanks for the replies.

Comment: @PartyArk I'm glad you understand it now. By the time I added the answer, I didn't realize that hoisting was confusing you. And the article you linked in the other comment above is excellent indeed, I was about to point you to the same link.

Answer (score 1):

This will throw an error because the variable is not found in the context-chain of the current execution context. Accessing a variable that cannot be resolved will result in an error.

```
_gaq = _gaq || [];
```

This, on the other hand, will try to resolve _gac trying to look for it as a member of the window object, wich turns out to be the global context 'holder' object. The difference in this case is that it will not throw an error, but the the `window._gaq` will return undefined, because the property is not found in the window object.

```
_gaq = window._gaq || [];
```

So, since the global context object is the window (when speaking about browsers), if _gaq is defined, this two statements will have the same effect. The difference will be noticed when _gaq is not defined, and accessing to it using the window object can have the advantage of not getting an error.

Answer (score 1):

There underlying concept here is [hoisting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14299659/questions-on-javascript-hoisting) and it is often tricky in practice. Variables are defined at the top of a function's scope while the assignment still occurs where it is defined.

With this `var _gaq = _gaq` the variable is actually defined *before* the actual line of code for the assignment is executed. This means that when the assignment occurs the variable is already on the window scope. Without the var in front of _gaq no hoisting occurs and thus _gaq does not yet exists when the assignment runs causing the reference error.

If you want to see this in action you can check when the _gaq variable is added to the window object with the following:

```
function printIsPropOnWindow(propToCheck)
{
    for (prop in window)
    {
        if (prop == propToCheck)
        {
            console.warn('YES, prop ' + prop + ' was on the window object');
            return;
        }
    }
    console.warn('NO, prop ' + propToCheck + ' was NOT on the window object');
}


try {
    var _gaq = function() {
        printIsPropOnWindow("_gaq");
        return a;
    }();
} catch (ex) {
    printIsPropOnWindow("_gaq");
}
_gaq = "1";
printIsPropOnWindow("_gaq");
```

If you try this once as is and once with the var before _gaq removed you will see very different results because one has the _gaq hoisted and the other does not.

Comment: Thank you. I think my fundamental misunderstanding is that writing `foo = true` is exactly the same as writing `var foo = true`, and that in the first case the 'var' was implicit. To be fair, I think this is a fairly common misconception, because for most purposes they are the same. As Bergi points out though, the first becomes a property of the window... and so does the second. Except it's not really: deleting it will fail. In some subtle way they are different.

Comment: @Party: The *difference* between `var foo = ...` and `foo = ...` in global scope has nothing to do with your problem though. Only the fact that variable declarations are hoisted.

Comment: @Party Ark: Felix Kling is right. The hoisting changes *when* foo is added to the window object. And your problem is that you are trying to assign that variable before it is added to the window scope so the line fails with error. If you have the var it is hoisted->which means it is added to the window object at the very beginning of whatever scope you are in.

Comment: @Felix thanks, but it is at the root of the misunderstanding. It has always looked to me that the 'var' in a global scope declaration is _unneccessary_; that the two statements are _entirely identical_ and that the 'var' is _implicit_ - I thought that if a variable is unassigned its declaration is _automatically_ added to the global scope and so the two statements would be treated by the engine _in entirely the same fashion_. **This is wrong!!** I now know. It is understanding the nature of **undeclared assignments** that makes it easy to see why the assignment is failing.

Comment: @Party: Ah I see now. Nevertheless I spent some time to go through the steps that happen when the assignment takes place, maybe it still helps.