# why does javascript access value from parent scope in one function and not in another?

Tags: javascript, scope

Why is the second code snippet is behaving unexpectedly?

This question is different from [Questions on Javascript hoisting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14299659/questions-on-javascript-hoisting), because this question includes an IIFE, a Local scope, and is an attempt to better understand parent scope.

---

This function outputs correctly

```
var one = 1;
function sayOne() {
    console.log(one); // actually gets the value from the global scope
}
sayOne();
```

Output:

> 1

---

But this one does not.

```
var one = 1;
function sayDoom() {
    console.log(one); // somehow does not get the value from parent scope
    var one = 2;
    console.log(one);
    (function() {
        var one = 3;
        console.log(one); // displays correctly
    })();
}
sayDoom();
```

Output:

> undefined
>   2
>   3

Expected:

> 1
>   2
>   3

Comment: In `sayDoom`, you're experiencing `hoisting`, where locally declared variables (in a function) are hoisted up. You're seeing `undefined`, because the variable is "available" (through hoisting), but it just hasn't been assigned a value yet. Simply, a `var` declaration in a function, regardless of where it's placed in the code (top, middle, or bottom of the code block), will always be referenced thanks to hoisting.

Comment: @JackPattishall you accidentally posted your answer in the form of a comment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Questions on Javascript hoisting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14299659/questions-on-javascript-hoisting)

Comment: It's exactly equivalent to other questions about hoisting. The IIFE has no relevance to anything. Which parent scope do you believe a value is being accessed from?

Comment: Just put your variables declarations at the top of the function and stop worrying about hoisting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, JavaScript declarations are **hoisted**. So, a variable can be declared after it has been used. In other words; a variable can be used before it has been declared. Because of this, Javascript will read your function like this:

```
var one = 1;
function sayDoom() {
    var one;
    console.log(one); // one is not defined in the current scope
    one = 2;
    console.log(one);
    (function() {
        var one = 3;
        console.log(one);
    })();
}
sayDoom();
```

Comment: This is the best explanation so far.

Answer (score 4):

In javascript due to variable hoisting if you refer to a variable before its declared it will return undefined

actually the code becomes like this

```
function sayDoom() {
    var one;               // global variable wont be accssible now
    console.log(one); // returns undefined
    one = 2;
    console.log(one);
    (function() {
        var one = 3;
        console.log(one); // displays correctly
    })();
}
sayDoom();
```

you can access your global `one` variable using `this.one` inside the `sayDoom()` function

**edit** if your using strict mode this wont work

Comment: +1. Note that `this.one` won't work to access the global variable if you're in strict mode. I prefer using `window` to access global variables, e.g. `window.one`.

Comment: The question only refers to a "parent scope", which is not necessarily global: `function outer() { var one = 1; function sayOne() { console.log(one); } sayOne(); }`

Comment: @melpomene for that he needs to understand closures

Comment: @Matt Browne, it is still hard for me to understand why this.one hoists itself into the fuction of another function.  I accept it as the case and functionality and have used it as well.  But truely understanding it, I don't know.

Comment: @AlexanderDixon the variable is not being hoisted into the closure, a separate variable is being declared within that scope.